# MySQL counting without count function?

Tags: mysql, count

Database: `tennis`, ie a tennis club.

Table discussed: `penalties`

Columns: `paymentno`, `amount`, `playerno`

Task:

- Classify the penalty amounts as high, medium, low - Done !
- Then, count the number of penalties in low category - Need help.

How do I do part 2 without using a count function ? Is this possible ?

SQL query for 1:

```
use tennis;

select tennis.penalties.paymentno, 
       tennis.penalties.amount, 
       tennis.penalties.playerno,
       case 
         when playerno >= 0 and  playerno <= 40 then 'low'
         when playerno > 40 and  playerno < 80 then 'medium'
         when playerno > 80 then 'high'
       end
from tennis.penalties;
```

Thanks.

Comment: OK. I ask because "don't use COUNT()" looks like a stupid professor trick to me.  Why in the name of Dennis Ritchie and Jon Postel would you try to do something the hard way in SQL when the easy way is, well, easy?

Comment: @Ollie Jones: what is the *easy* way with `count()`? I'm sure it's not easier than the solution with `sum()`

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(playerno >= 0 and playerno <= 40) AS count_penalties_in_low
```

or

```
SUM(CASE WHEN playerno >= 0 and playerno <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_penalties_in_low
```

So technically you summarize 1s, which in fact equals to count

PS:

```
playerno >= 0 and  playerno <= 40
```

can be rewritten to

```
playerno BETWEEN 0 AND 40
```

PPS:

`playerno` = 80 isn't covered by any condition

PPPS: I'd write that case in this way:

```
   case 
     when playerno <= 40 then 'low'
     when playerno <= 80 then 'medium'
                         else 'high'
   end
```

PPPPS: the solution without functions (concept)

```
SELECT @I:=@I+1, other_columns FROM table, (SELECT @I:=0) x
```

and having @I you can count what you want

But it is terrible solution in this case

Comment: I will try this soon. But my textbook has not mentioned any functions yet. So, is there a way to do it without any functions ?

Comment: @user1499832: yep, there is a way

Comment: wow ! can you explain the last solution ? Its new to me. I know that the @XXXX is a user varibale.

Comment: @user1499832: `(SELECT @I:=0) x` is a nested query, which returns one line and joins to the `table`. After that on each row expression `@I:=@I+1` is evaluated. Which: a) increments the value b) returns the new value